# SharePoint Online Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-online

I would like to connect a SharePoint Online with the current user on .NET with Single Sign On. I don't want to specify a username and password in my code. Unfortunately, I've the following error message on `ExecuteQuery()`:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

My code:

```
string siteCollectionUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/teams/yyyy";
System.Net.ICredentials credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
SharePoint.ClientContext context = new SharePoint.ClientContext(siteCollectionUrl);
context.Credentials = credentials;
SharePoint.Web web = context.Web;
context.Load(web);
context.ExecuteQuery();
string tt = web.Title;
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj164693(v=office.15)) class for authentication.

Like this:

```
String name = "user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
String password = "xxxx";
SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}
var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(name, securePassword);
string siteCollectionUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/teams/yyyy";

ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteCollectionUrl );
ctx.Credentials = credentials;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I need connect to SharePoint Online with the user who's running the program by Sigle Sign On. I don't want to specify username and password in my code. I just modify my question to be more clear.